# login form email id will display in password reset form using ajax success function without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

**In login form if click the forgot link next password reset div will open in that email will display in email field  same as in login form. without page refresh how to display email in ajax success function and both form are in same page**

**login**

```
<div class="form-div active" id="login-form"> 
     <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Index.php/Login_cntrl/login" method="POST" >

                        <div class="field-wrap">
                            <label class="view-label">Email Address</label>
                            <input type="email" placeholder=" Email Address" name="email" id="email" class="input-control" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="field-wrap">
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" />
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('password'); ?></span>

                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn-nobg" id="btn-show-forgot" >Forgot ?</a>  

                        </div> 
</div>
```

**script**

```
$('#btn-show-forgot').click(function () {

                    $('.form-div').removeClass("active");
                    $('#forgot-form').addClass("active");
                    currentActiveId = "forgot-form";
                    sessionStorage.setItem('activeDiv', currentActiveId);
```

**password reset form**

```
<div class="form-div" id="forgot-form"> 
<div class="field-wrap">
                            <input type="text" name="emaill" id="emaill" placeholder="Enter your Mobile/Email Address" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('findemaill'); ?>" />

                        </div>
</div>
```

**ajax/jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btn-show-forgot").click(function () {
                    //e.preventDefault();
                    var email = $("#email").val();
                    //  var password= $("#password").val();


                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>" + "Index.php/Login_cntrl/sendmail",
                        data: {email: email},
                        success: function (data)
                        {
//                            alert('Successfully send a mail');

//location.reload();
//here i want to display,first form email id without page refresh

                        },
                        error: function ()
                        {
                            alert('fail');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: use 2 form in a single page and show login form by default. If some one clicked on forgot password then hide login form and show forgot password form by using hide() and show() event of jquery

Comment: same like that only working but second form email field without reload value should be display using ajax/jquery success function

Comment: just take the email from login form and put it on forgot passowrd form by using .val()

Comment: how give me one example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Login form   
 <form name="login" id="login">
    <input type="text" id="login_email" name="login_email" />
    <input type="password" name="login_password" />
   <button id="forgot-password">Forgot password</button>
  </form>

// Forgotpassword form

    <form name="forgotForm" id="forgotForm" style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" name="forgot_email" id="forgot_email" />
    </form>

JQuery

$("#forgot-password").on("click",function(){
  $("#login").hide();
  $("#forgotForm").show();
  var loginVal = $("#login_email").val();
 $("#forgot_email").val(loginVal);
});
```